# Windows server TImeZone not correct

Tags: windows-server-2008

The timezone setting changes, but the time it reflects is not the time for that timezone. How to synch it all up? i have windows time service running. im on a domain.

Comment: What timezone(s) are we talking about, how are you trying to change it and what's telling you that it's not right.

Comment: i change it to say Eastern time and it show 10:30pm even though its 5:30pm on the east coast. (on windows desktop clock)

Comment: Have you tried fixing the timezone, and then setting the correct time?

Comment: yes and it reverts back when i log in

Comment: i am on a cloud hosting service as well.

Comment: How does the time look on your Domain Controller and what does w32tm /query /configuration tell you.

Answer (score 0):

w32tm is your friend.

Confirm where the server is synchronising the time from as it obviously overriding the time you manually set, by running:

```
w32tm /query /peers
```

By default this will be a coming from a domain controller. You would then determine that that machine is configured correctly. And where it is getting its time from. If it has no peer you can set it manually or ideally you should set it to be a machine on the internet. Search for Public NTP server on google.

You can also manually set peers on the server you are having problems with again using w32tm.